# remove element from array and reindex from 0

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array (
    [REF_DETAILS] = Array
        (
            [0] = Array
                (
                    [ID] =&gt; 1231312
                    [USER] =&gt; USER
                )

            [1] = Array
                (
                    [TID] =&gt; 2754042         
                    [USER] = USER
                )
            [1] = Array
                (
                    [TID] =&gt; 534535         
                    [USER] = USER
                )

        )

    [TOTAL_COUNT] = 31
)
```

I have a array output like this above and I want to remove one element from the array then again i want to reindex it from 0. I tried with array_value in php but after doing this it is removing [REF_DETAIL] with 0 and TOTAL_COUNT as 1 , please provide the solution in php

Comment: The sample data is impossible.  Duplicate keys may not exist on a single level in an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
unset($array['REF_DETAILS'][1]);
$array['REF_DETAILS'] = array_values($array['REF_DETAILS']);
```

Comment: very expensive solution if the arrays get bigger.

Answer (score 5):

Use `array_splice` ([php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)), it automatically reindexes.

`array_splice($array['REF_DETAILS'], 1, 1)`

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_shift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

```
$arr = Array (
    'REF_DETAILS' => Array(
        0 => Array(
            'ID' => '&gt; 1231312',
            'USER' => '&gt; USER',
        ),
        1 => Array(
            'TID' => '&gt; 2754042         ',
            'USER' => 'USER',
        ),
        2 => Array(
            'TID' => '&gt; 534535         ',
            'USER' => 'USER',
        ),
    ),
    'TOTAL_COUNT' => 31,
);

array_shift($arr['REF_DETAILS']);
print_r($arr);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [REF_DETAILS] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [TID] => &gt; 2754042
                    [USER] => USER
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [TID] => &gt; 534535
                    [USER] => USER
                )

        )

    [TOTAL_COUNT] => 31
)
```